# Inherited Resources and optional belongs_to: How to scope collection in parent resource, but not in nested resource?

Tags: inherited-resources

I have the following routes:

```
resources :boilerplates
resources :projects do
  resources :boilerplates
end
```

The `Boilerplate` model looks like this:

```
class Boilerplate < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :originals, -> { where(prototype_id: nil) }
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
class BoilerplatesController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
  belongs_to :project, optional: true
end
```

When the URL `/boilerplates` is opened, I want to display all boilerplates with the `originals` scope.

When the URL `/projects/123/boilerplates` is opened, I want the `originals` scope not to be active.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to do this myself. In `BoilerplatesController`:

```
protected

def collection
  if @project
    super
  else
    super.originals
  end
end
```